# Is it a good practice to create methods inside an abstract class and not override them inside the class which extends it?

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, abstract

I have got a question.

Should I create getter and setter methods inside abstract class? The below example contains these methods inside abstract class which is extended by Individual class. Is it a good practice to have different variety on methods inside abstract class? Should I be overriding those methods inside Individual class? However it doesn't make sense for me to override those as these will not do anything different, just set and get different attributes. Any advice?

```
public abstract class Human {
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public Human(String name, String surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
}


public class Individual extends Human{
    private String dob;

    public Individual(String name, String surname, String dob) {
        super(name, surname);
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public void viewIndividual(){
        System.out.println("First name of individual is: " + getName());
        System.out.println("Surname of individual is: " + getSurname());
        System.out.println("Date of birth of individual is: " + getDob());
    }
}
```

Comment: It is ok. But the point of an abstract class is to have at least an abstract method.

Comment: That's exactly the point of abstract classes (in contrast to interfaces), that you can define _some_ methods that do not have to be overwritten.

Comment: Subclasses of an abstract class must implement (override) all abstract methods of its abstract superclass. The non-abstract methods of the superclass are just inherited as they are. They can also be overridden, if needed .

Comment: It is bad practice to have getters and setters period. You are treating your classes as nothing but dumb bags of data. Think about objects in terms of their *behaviour*. In your case, you should be able to print an `Individual`. Maybe that's all it can do, and that's fine. Why should you need to be able to change every field?

Comment: There's nothing abstract in `Human` class, unless you have specific behavior to be provided in subclasses, then you have to pull up that behavior as an abstract method/s. I wouldn't make `Human` abstract. It's just a POJO.

Comment: If you think some _default_ methods of your abstract class shouldn't be overridable you can make them `final`. Other implementations of the class will of course use / access those methods, but can't override them.

Comment: Two classes shown above are just for example and do not represent a real-life problem. I got to know that methods can be written within an abstract class and be also inherited by a class and do not have to be overridden.

Comment: What do you mean by "Is it a good practice to have different variety on methods inside abstract class?"?

Comment: The methods in the abstract class is meant for handling business methods rather than getter and setter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I create getter and setter methods inside abstract class?

Yes, if a method is common to most expected implementations of an abstract class, it's perfectly fine to implement those methods in the abstract class. If it's really good to have getters and setters for the properties of your `Human`, it hard to say. The way you're currently using it, it doesn't make much sense, as you're mixing behavior aspects (viewIndividual) with data aspects (getters and setters) in one class. Given the code above you would be fine with protected members in the abstract class, and potentially setters to avoid code duplication in the implementations. But if you want to use your objects as Java-Beans, it's fine.

> Is it a good practice to have different variety on methods inside abstract class?

You mean both, abstract and non-abstract methods? Yes, this is pretty standard. Take this example:

```
public abstract class Example {

  public final void publicMethod() {
    // do some preparations
    internalMethod();
    // do some cleanup
  }

  protected abstract void internalMethod();
}
```

Consumers of implementations of `Example` will only be able to access `publicMethod` and it is guaranteed that all needed preparations and cleanup tasks are executed without repeating this code over and over again in the implementations of `Example` as only `internalMethod` needs to be overridden.

> Should I be overriding those methods inside Individual class?

No, definitively not. At least as long as you don't add additional functionality to the methods, abstract methods should not be overridden just for implementing them inside the  instantiatable class.

In general you should be careful with inheritance as code tends to become very hard to understand, if you implement something in a deep type hierarchy. IMHO hierarchies start to become hard to use with a hierarchy level of 4-5 already, but this is probably heavily opinion based. There is the rule to prefer composition over inheritance to avoid over-exhaustive use of inheritance for simple utility stuff.